# Question on Dirichlet density

Tags: number-theory, algebraic-number-theory, analytic-number-theory

I did not understand the highlighted sentence of the exercise below:
[image]

My question is:  how does it follow that $f(x)=0$ has ***a*** solution mod $p$ implies that $f(x)$ (mod $p$)  splits as the product of linear factors in $\Bbb{Z}/p\Bbb{Z}$, i.e has all the roots in  $\Bbb{Z}/p\Bbb{Z}$?

Comment: I'm not sure, but it seems to me that an *irreducible* **normal** *polynomial of degree* $n$ here means a polynomial with the property that you get its splitting field by adjoining one (any one) of its roots. This means that the other roots can be written as polynomials with rational coefficients in the first one. Those polynomials either have integer coefficients or, failing that, the denominators of their coefficients have only finitely many prime factors. Therefore the polynomials make sense modulo $p$ for (almost) all primes $p$. The claim follows from this.

Comment: It might be easier to see what's going on if we can see Theorem 5.5.1 and Exercise 5.5.2.